# Why is Axios Delete giving me a 404 error?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, axios

Although the URLs in my React App and in my Express app seem to match I cannot get the Axios.delete to work. I get the console log error

> 'Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404'.

Can anyone spot what i'm doing wrong? I'm fairly new to React. Any help, appreciated.

Here is the front end code:

```
  Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/delete/${id}`)
}
```

Here is the back end:

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  db.query("DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ?", id, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.send(result)
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Do you get the id in the backend? You may be sending `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Any errors in the web console or network tab? That looks like a cross-origin call. Cross-origin `DELETE` requires the server to specifically allow it via CORS.

Comment: The correct id is being passed through. Console error: xhr.js:177 DELETE http://localhost:3001/delete/1 404 (Not Found). Also I've got CORS included.

Comment: I your URL correct?

Answer (score -1):

I think in your backend you need to access the id like this

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  db.query("DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ?", id, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.send(result)
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck, I did destructuring the id initially but it didn't make a difference. This problem has me stumped!

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone for your help. The solution was embarrassingly simple - to restart the server. I'd tried everything and was tearing my hair out and then the restart resolved the problem!
Thank you all for your time and effort :).